# Laravel custom basic auth - Only username

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom basic auth which pop-up an authentication page requesting username and password. But after hooking it up with my route, it just not working.

Here is the auth class

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class SxroAuthenticateWithBasicAuth implements Middleware
{
  /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard $auth
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $this->auth->basic('username') ?: $next($request);
    }
}
```

I want to login to be `username` instead of `email`, So I believe I got things right.  But Why is not working??

I got the kernel setup like this

```
'auth.sxro' => \App\Http\Middleware\SxroAuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
```

When I enter username and password.

[image]

It just won't work, and keeps popping up again. Someone tell me what's going on? How can I debug this?

Comment: Any news about this buddy? did you make any success with customizing it